watchOS live audio stream from watch itself
I would like to stream live audio (hls) from watch itself, our app can start stream on paired device, but when phone is not near by i want to start streaming on watchos (just like spotify or Apple music app) I watched the 2019 wwdc video about streaming and also looked to the documentation
Documentation : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_support/playing_background_audio
here is the logs;
[Routing] Presenting route picker alert for audioSessionID: 401593

true
(success variable in the AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().activate completion handler)
nil
(error variable in the AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().activate completion handler)
Stream URL:
"https://listen.powerapp.com.tr/powerfm/abr/playlist.m3u8"

I can present the route controller to select output, but for example after selecting Air Pods, stream did not start..
Here is the code: (I have enabled background mode audio)
do {
try  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, policy: .longFormAudio, options: \[\])
}
catch {
print("no audiosession!")
}

AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().activate(options: \[\]) { success, error in
dump(success)
dump(error)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
if let streamURL = moduleItem.media?\[0\] as? String {
dump(streamURL)
let asset  = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: streamURL)!, options: nil)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: item)
player.play()
}
}
}

followed the 2019 WWDC video about streaming:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/716/
Read the official sample in documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_support/playing_background_audio

any clues in the console log?

Nothing in the logs, after selecting audio route,  the AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().activate completion handler called and the success is true and error is nil
